# Wordpress site redirecting constantly on index

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I'm migrating a Wordpress site from Apache configuration to Nginx configuration. Currently I have this

```
user www-data www-data;
events {}

http {
    upstream php {
        server unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    server {
        server_name starter.mper.dev;
        root /var/www/wp-starter;
        index index.php;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_pass php;
        }
    }
}
```

configuration for my Wordpress Docker container and an Nginx Proxy Manager that handles SSL certification and routing on the host machine.
The Wordpress Docker container listens on port 80 and all requests to the host machine on port 8110 are passed to the Wordpress Docker container. However, accessing https://starter.mper.dev ends up creating an endless 301 redirect loop and site never loads. Any idea what might be causing this issue?